# How to output the price when clicking the radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<fieldset style="width:240 px">
   <legend>Food order</legend>
   <fieldset style="width:240 px">
   <legend>Nasi Lemak</legend> 
   
   <p>
    <input type="radio"  name="j"  value="2"
    onclick="calculate();" />
    <label for='small' class="inlinelabel">
    Small</label>
     (RM2)
   </p>

   <p>
    <input type="radio"  name="j"  value="3"
    onclick="calculate();" />
    <label for='regular' class="inlinelabel">
    Regular</label>
     (RM3)
   </p>

   <p>
    <input type="radio" name="j"   value="4"
    onclick="calculate();" />
    <label for='large' class="inlinelabel">
    Large</label>
     (RM4)
   </p>



   <tr>
    <td>Price = </td>
    <td><output type="number" name="price" id="output"></output></td>
   </tr>
 

   </fieldset>





<script type="text/javascript">
            calculate()
{

}
      

</script>
```

Does anyone know how to output the price when clicking the radio button ? Let say if i choose Small then it will display the output Rm2...for example Price = Rm 2....i have no idea how to continue it...i will very appreciate it if someone help me solve this...thanks ~

Comment: You won't be able to do this with only html. It would require some javascript

Comment: but at the below i got add <script type="text/javascript"> </script>...html combine with javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass as parameter `this` in calculate function(this refers to the element).

Using jquery:

```js
function calculate(obj) {
  $("output").text(obj.value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset style="width:240 px">
  <legend>Food order</legend>
  <fieldset style="width:240 px">
    <legend>Nasi Lemak</legend>

    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="j" value="2" onclick="calculate(this);" />
      <label for='small' class="inlinelabel">
        Small</label>
      (RM2)
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="j" value="3" onclick="calculate(this);" />
      <label for='regular' class="inlinelabel">
        Regular</label>
      (RM3)
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="j" value="4" onclick="calculate(this);" />
      <label for='large' class="inlinelabel">
        Large</label>
      (RM4)
    </p>



    <tr>
      <td>Price =</td>
      <td>
        <output type="number" name="price" id="output"></output>
      </td>
    </tr>


  </fieldset>
```

Using plain **js**:

```js
function calculate(obj) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = obj.value;
}
```

```html
<fieldset style="width:240 px">
  <legend>Food order</legend>
  <fieldset style="width:240 px">
    <legend>Nasi Lemak</legend>

    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="j" value="2" onclick="calculate(this);" />
      <label for='small' class="inlinelabel">
        Small</label>
      (RM2)
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="j" value="3" onclick="calculate(this);" />
      <label for='regular' class="inlinelabel">
        Regular</label>
      (RM3)
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="radio" name="j" value="4" onclick="calculate(this);" />
      <label for='large' class="inlinelabel">
        Large</label>
      (RM4)
    </p>



    <tr>
      <td>Price =</td>
      <td>
        <output type="number" name="price" id="output"></output>
      </td>
    </tr>


  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
document.getElementsByName("j").addEventListener("change", function(){
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = this.value;// Show the value in output element

      //or

    var myRadioValue= this.value; //for some calculate
});
```

Comment: put inside the calculate(){}  ?

Comment: Dont need. This implementation takes the radio value and show in the <output></output>. If you want to work with that values. You can use this.value inside de change event. I ll edit.

Comment: You dont need the onclick event anymore.